# comparing sum() to other rows of sum

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, aggregate-functions

so i have this table

```
type   total
------------
A    |  50
A    |  50
B    |  100
C    |  50
C    |  200
D    |  150
D    |  300
```

this code just for reference

> ```
> select type,Sum(total)
> From table A
> group by type
> ```

I'd like to get all types that doesnt have the same Sum() with other types
so in SQL i would have something like this

```
my expected output is 

type    total
-------------
C    |  250
D    |  450
```

because type A = 100 and theres type B who is also = 100

Comment: Always include your Oracle version. For example, in my solutions I use subfactored queries whenever they make sense - but they are only available since Oracle 11.1. If your version is 10 or below, the query must be rewritten using the "old" subquery syntax.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions:

```
select type, total
from (select type, sum(total) as total,
             count(*) over (partition by sum(total)) as cnt
      from table A
      group by type
     ) a
where cnt = 1;
```

Comment: is there a simpler way of doing this without using partition by?

Comment: `partition by` *is* the simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Using GROUP BY twice - first group by type to compute the grand totals, and then by grand total to remove the ones with "equal" grand totals:

```
with
     inputs ( type, total ) as (
       select 'A',  50 from dual union all
       select 'A',  50 from dual union all
       select 'B', 100 from dual union all
       select 'C',  50 from dual union all
       select 'C', 200 from dual union all
       select 'D', 150 from dual union all
       select 'D', 300 from dual
     ),
     grouped ( type, grand_total ) as (
       select type, sum(total)
       from   inputs
       group by type
     )
select max(type) as type, grand_total
from   grouped
group by grand_total
having count(type) = 1
;


TYPE GRAND_TOTAL
---- -----------
D            450
C            250

2 rows selected.
```